# ag-Grid: tried to call sizeColumnsToFit() but the grid is coming back with zero width, maybe the grid is not visible yet on the screen?

Tags: angularjs, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag

```
 # in html xyz.commponent.tz

<tabset #staticTabs>
    <tab heading="User">
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
        class="ag-theme-material"
        [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Whitelisted User" >
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
        class="ag-theme-material"
        [rowData]="rowData1"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs1"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="Blacklisted User">
      <ag-grid-angular
        style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
        class="ag-theme-material"
        [rowData]="rowData2"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs2"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      >
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </tab>

  </tabset>
#in xyz.component.ts
constructor() {
this.gridOptions = {
  onGridReady: () => {
    this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  },
};}
```

I want to resize all  3 ag-grid but no one is resized. it gives no error in the console but shows this ag-Grid: tried to call sizeColumnsToFit() but the grid is coming back with zero width, maybe the grid is not visible yet on the screen?

Comment: have you defined widths to parent divs of ag-grid?

Comment: i am not set any width .

Comment: try setting a fixed width to your ag grid in px instead of 100%

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 4):

This has been one of the issues of ag-grid angular which was resolved in v16 when they introduced this callback - `onFirstDataRendered`

Try invoking resize code in `onFirstDataRendered` instead of `onGridReady`-

```
  onFirstDataRendered(params) {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
```

You can also try using a small timeout while calling `sizeColumnsToFit` in `onGridReady` if you are on some older version.

As per docs -

> Note that api.sizeColumnsToFit() needs to know the grid width in order
>   to do its maths. If the grid is not attached to the DOM, then this
>   will be unknown. In the example below, the grid is not attached to the
>   DOM when it is created (and hence api.sizeColumnsToFit() should fail).
>   The grid checks again after 100ms, and tries to resize again. This is
>   needed for some frameworks (e.g. Angular) as DOM objects are used
>   before getting attached.

Example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#example-default-resizing)

Comment: it only fit the first tab not the other tab and shows this error -- _co.onFirstDataRendered is not a function

Comment: you need to use different gridOptions for each grid instance. I see you are sharing the same gridOptions

Comment: I had a similar issue where sizeColumnsToFit() wasn't working correctly even when I was calling it from onFirstDataRendered(). So I used setTimeout to call sizeColumnsToFit() after a 50 ms delay, and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but the current answer didn't help me and I found this via a google search.

I had the same issue using angular material tabs. First tab was fine, but subsequent tabs failed to call sizeColumnsToFit since they were not visible in DOM until the tab is selected.

I tried various [grid events](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/?) such as viewportChanged, firstDataRendered, etc... but nothing worked. I ended up calling sizeColumnsToFit() within the child component after the tab was selected. There are a number of ways to do that, but I chose to use an observable to update what tab was selected and then trigger the api.sizeColumnsToFit().

Comment: Hmm, this is quite a shame.  I'm having the same issue.  If you do it during a tab selection that would mean the table won't render correctly until a user interacts with it?